# Browser is automatically adding a <s> tag into html error

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm customizing a [dotdigital WordPress theme](http://webdesign-finder.com/dotdigital-marketing/) on a client's domain [247btl.com](https://www.247btl.com/). I've been making a few style changes, and middle of it this error popped up. Below each section browser is adding `<s>` tag.

[image: error-screenshot]

I reverted back to the original stylesheet, but the error persisted. Any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser not auto add this tag, it's you or the coder mistake. Take a look in to the header section, where contains the phone number. Remove the `<s>` then you're good to go.

[image]